# "Locally measurable"

Tags: measure-theory

[In this set of notes](http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/greenbj/papers/rkp.pdf) on page 30, Green refers to a function $f$ on $S^1$ which is "locally measurable".  Given the context, I think what he means is a function $f$ defined on $\mathbb{R}^2$ whose restriction to $S^1$ is measurable.  I was hoping someone could clarify.

Answer (score 4):

Let $(X, \mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a measure space, then $E\subset X$ is a *locally measurable set* if for every measurable set $A$ with finite measure, $E\cap A$ is also measurable. 
A function $f$ is *locally measurable* if it is measurable with respect to the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the locally measurable sets.